# hadoop mapred job - Error initializing attempt mapred task

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hdfs

I accidentally deleted hadoop.tmp.dir, in my case /tmp/{user.name}/*. Now everytime when I run hive query from CLI, and the mapred job will fail at the task attempt as below:

```
Error initializing attempt_201202231712_1266_m_000009_0:
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find any valid local     directory for ttprivate/taskTracker/hdfs/jobcache/job_201202231712_1266/jobToken
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:376)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:146)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:127)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJobTokenFile(TaskTracker.java:4432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeJob(TaskTracker.java:1301)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:1242)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.startNewTask(TaskTracker.java:2541)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$TaskLauncher.run(TaskTracker.java:2505)
```

It's a test environment, I don't care about the data. How can I get the system back to normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should call stop-all.sh file , recreate the file and start after formatting the tmp file

Comment: Can you be more specific? by stop-all.sh, u meant i should reboot my hadoop cluster?

Comment: Yes I meant that you should call the script file stop-all.sh , and configure your DFS as you did the time you installed it

Comment: got you, I am using the cloudera version, weird enough, it doesn't have that script. But I restarted the cluster anyway. I finally noticed that my task-tracker node is running out of disk space. Will try to free some space see if it heals the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can just simple recreate the directory and change the owner of the file to mapred. `chown mapred:mapred <your dir>`